# g++ -O optimizations

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
        int n = 100;
        long a = 0;
        int *x = new int[n];

        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                        for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
                                for(int l = 0; l < n; ++l)
                                {   

                                        a += x[(j + k + l) % 100];
                                }   
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
        delete[] x;
        return 0;
}
```

If I compile without optimizations g++ test.cc and then run time ./a.out it will display 0.7s. However when I compile it with -O, the time decreases by 2 times.

**Compiler used**

```
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2
```

**My question**

How can I rewrite the code so when compiling without -O I can obtain same time ( or close to it ) ? In other words, **how to optimize nested loops manually** ?

**Why I ask**

I have a similar code which runs about 4 times faster if I use -O optimization.

PS: I've looked in the manual of the compiler but there are way too many flags there to test which one really makes the difference.

Comment: -O2 does "every optimization that does not trade space for speed", so it's likely that the compiler optimizes out the majority of these loops, replacing them with compile-time math (i.e. constants). Personally I'm unable to do this in my head, but the compiler sure can figure out how to do addding the same array element a few times in fewer OPs. GCC is particularly good at doing awesome compile-time stuff. So it will boil down to a single or maybe two nested loops only... which is why it's faster. Having said that, compile with `-save-temps` and look at the `.s` file. Then you know for sure.

Comment: Why are you asking? If you want more optimizations, tell the compiler. There's a list of optimizations that are implied by `-O2` but not by `-O`. If you want both to produce similar code, you need to write code that doesn't benefit from any of the optimizations `-O2` adds. I don't know what those are, but I'd guess there are many general-purpose ones among them. You won't help yourself by manually adding them or sacrifice a goat to prevent them from applying to your code.

Comment: @Alessandro Pezzato: all elements of an array are initialized with the default constructor of the type.

Comment: So... the compiler is able to optimize your similar code. Sounds like everything's working as intended. Like delnan said, if you want it fast, tell the compiler to optimize. There's no point asking how to do it yourself. The compiler does all kinds of things for you. Let it!

Comment: QtLearner: Forget it. You can't possibly achieve what you want. If you really want to learn why, you have to compile with -S and look at the machine code that the compiler generates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the things the compiler optimizes with -O are things on a level below C++. For example, all variables live in memory, including your loop variables. Therefore without optimization, the compiler will most likely on each iteration of the inner loop first read the loop variable to compare it with 0, inside the loop load it again in order to use it for the index, and then at the end of the loop will read the value again, increment it, and write it back. With optimization, it will notice that the loop variable is not changed in the loop body, and therefore does not need to get re-read from memory each time. Moreover it will also note that the address of the variable is never taken, so no other code will ever access it, and therefore writing it to memory can also be omitted. That is, the loop variable will live only in memory. This optimization alone will save three hundred million memory reads and one hundred million memory writes during execution of your function. But since things like processor registers and memory reads/writes are not exposed at the language level, there's no way to optimize it at the language level.

Furthermore, it doesn't make sense to hand-optimize things which the compiler optimizes anyway. Better spend your time at optimizing things which the compiler *cannot* optimize.

Answer (score 3):

This code has undefined behaviour, so actually the optimizer can do whatever it wants..

```
a += x[j + k + l % 100];
```

should be:

```
a += x[(j + k + l) % 100];
```

If you fix this I still don't get why you want to optimize something that actually doesn't do anything...

Personally I would optimize this to: :)

```
std::cout << 0 << std::endl;
```

Note: remove the loop for `i` and do `std::cout << a * n << std::endl;`

Comment: I want to optimize this because I have a more complicated program with nested loops and it's not fast enough. When I use -O2 it's around 4 times faster than with no optimizations.

Comment: Also, just remove the outermost loop and multiply a by n for the final result.  See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization

Comment: It's a homework, others might copy my code if they find it since the deadline has not passed. It's something similar anyway, it just contains a few more variable in the nested section and a lot of conditions.

Comment: @QtLearner: I can't help because what you're asking for doesn't make sense. read the comments.

Comment: @QtLearner: depends on the actual loops... since this is not the code you want to optimize, how could i help? :/

Answer (score 1):

You could observe that your loops form a set of coefficients `coeff[i]` such that a single loop summing `a[i] * coeff[i]` produces the same total as the nested loop.  If we assume your index was meant to be `(i + j + k) % 100` then `coeff[i] = n * n * n` for all `i`, so your whole program simplifies to

```
long coeff = n * n * n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++n)
    a += x[i] * coeff;
```

which I'm sure runs in far less than 0.7 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a polynomial time algorithm (`n ** 4`) so it stands to reason it'll be slow, especially for larger `n`. Perhaps an algorithm with a lower complexity would help you?

If you want your code optimized you can either ask the compiler to optimize for you, or just write it in assembly language and be done with it. Don't try to second-guess the C++ compiler.

Comment: I have tried to do all the optimization to the actual problem and decreased from O(n^6) to O(n^4). Now my only choice is the try to optimize the code.

Comment: @QtLearner: Then by that definition, it's not possible to optimize code for speed, because code is just a bunch of lexical characters. We typically refer to code and algorithm with the relationship that code *implements* and algorithm. To optimize code, you optimize the algorithm, which you've done. What you *should* do is use a profiler to really see which operations are using the most time.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I rewrite the code so when compiling without -O I can obtain same time ( or close to it ) ? In other words, how to optimize nested loops manually ?

You write them in assembly. Good luck with *that*, BTW.

The purpose of the optimization switches in compilers is for you to say, "Compiler, I want you to try to generate fast assembly." By default, compilers do not do optimizations, because those optimizations might inhibit the debugability of the resulting code. So you have to specifically ask for them.

The things the compiler does to optimize code are, generally speaking, not something you can do manually. Some can be (like loop unrolling), but others can't be.